# Database JDBC Find out open connections/sessions?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

Is there anyway we can find out the open connections at a time when doing JPA operations for example.

To be more clear, I am getting no buffer space available error. So I want to know if i can close down my connections in my code in order to avoid this error?

Or if i can monitor it using some monitor tool what is happening etc.

It is a help request, if you can help I will be thankful, if you can't help then why are you down voting? This discourages from asking for help.

Comment: Usually you use a connection pool that takes care of all connections maintenance. Take a look at [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) or [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/).

Comment: Actually it is not clear what do you mean. Holding list of opening connections is not a part of `JPA`, it is responsibility of the connection pool

Comment: @Magnamag I will be looking at these.

Comment: you can use a jdbc proxy driver like p6spy or log4jdbc to log when your connections open and close, so you can find out where the problem is.

Comment: Thank @Magnamag I am able to find out the connections in sql server management studio and mysql workbench too. and I have configured c3p0 successfully too.

Comment: Ok @NathanHughes I will look into this too.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it depends on the driver that your are using, some of them could have some way to know about it. But it is posible it could be a dangerous practice, because you could close a connection that is currently used.

The best way is to use a connection pool manager that take care about all the conections for instance:

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html

Or integrate your database conections into and ORM for example hibernate:

http://hibernate.org/